# Ubuntu says 'Unknown Audio Device' every time I plug my headphones in

Tags: 16.04, sound, headphones, microphone, headset

Every single time I plug them in it says they're an "unknown audio device" and asks me to select if they're headphones, a headset, or microphone. I'm tired of having to select one every time.

If it helps, they're Sennheiser Momentum over-ear headphones. I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 with all the latest updates.

Comment: Is the jack a microphone and headphone combo port?

Comment: Check to see what the icon is near the port. If that still doesn't help, it might be a problem with the headphones. How long have you had them?

Comment: I suppose it might be, because the headphones do have a microphone on the built-in volume control, so presumably the audio jack is both, yeah

Comment: Then that's why. The computer needs to know what you plugged in. Pushing the current required to drive headphones through a microphone would have bad effects.

Comment: But does the microphone work?

Comment: But why does it ask every single time? Can't it remember that these are a headset? The mic seems to work as it responds on the sound control panel

Comment: Remember, it's an analog device. It doesn't have an ID chip. How could the computer remember it?

Comment: Fair point. Is there any way of disabling the popup window entirely then? I don't see how it can be necessary when Windows 10 doesn't need to ask.

Comment: Hrmm. Good point as well. I suggest you wait for another user's opinion. Also, FYI, if you find the answer by jjaaccoobb unhelpful, you can downvote it.

Comment: Consider this though: On my PC Win7 asks what device I plugged it and Ubuntu doesn't :P